# Custom paging function

Tags: pagination

I use this code for my custom paging :

```
global $wpdb, $table_prefix, $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
$umail = $current_user->user_email;
$paged = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$table_prefix}comments WHERE comment_author_email = '$umail'");

$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? (int) $_GET['page'] : 1;
$pages = COUNT($paged);
$pages = ceil($pages / 2);

$querystring = "";
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
    if ($key != "page") $querystring .= "$key=$value&amp;";
}

// Pagination
for ($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
    echo "<a " . ($i == $page ? "class=\"selected\" " : "");
    echo "href=\"?{$querystring}page=$i";
    echo "\">$i</a> ";
}
```

This code paginate my comments look like this :
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11

How can change code to get paginate look like this:
1 2 3 ... 11

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of the loop at the bottom, use WordPress's `paginate_links()`:

```
$pagination = paginate_links(array(
    'total' => $pages,
    'current' => $page
));
echo $pagination;
```

You can play around with some of https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links to get the appearance the way you want. Specifically, the `end_size` and `mid_size` will help you to determine the number of page numbers that show, as in your example (1 2 3 ... 11).

If you want something *really* powerful, you can check out my Boone's Pagination plugin: http://teleogistic.net/2011/05/new-wordpress-plugin-boones-pagination/ (shameless plug!), though it may be too much for your use case :)

Comment: Not work, error : 'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW in '

Comment: @Nulled It was missing the array statement, fixed now (as soon as a moderator approves my edit anyways).